# Merge and Aggregate by multiple colums in r?

Tags: r

I have 2 tables. Below are the sample tables and the desired output.

```
Table1:

Start Date  End Date    Country
2017-01-04  2017-01-06   id
2017-02-13  2017-02-15   ng

Table2:

Transaction Date    Country Cost    Product
2017-01-04           id     111        21
2017-01-05           id     200        34
2017-02-14           ng     213        45
2017-02-15           ng     314        32
2017-02-18           ng     515        26

Output:

Start Date  End Date    Country Cost    Product
2017-01-04  2017-01-06  id      311          55
2017-02-13  2017-02-15  ng      527          77
```

The problem is to merge two tables when transaction date lies in between start date and end date & country matches. And add the values of cost and product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can use any of the `merge` operation here but one way using `mapply` is to subset the rows based on the condition and take the `sum` of `Product` and `Cost` columns.

```
df1[c("Cost", "Product")] <- t(mapply(function(x, y, z) {
     inds <- df2$Transaction_Date >= x & df2$Transaction_Date <= y & df2$Country == z
     c(sum(df2$Cost[inds]), sum(df2$Product[inds]))
     },df1$Start_Date, df1$End_Date, df1$Country))

df1
#  Start_Date   End_Date Country Cost Product
#1 2017-01-04 2017-01-06      id  311      55
#2 2017-02-13 2017-02-15      ng  527      77
```

Answer (score 3):

This calls for fuzzyjoins. Below are 2 examples.

Using dplyr and fuzzyjoin packages:

```
fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, 
                c("Country" = "Country",
                  "Start_Date" = "Transaction_Date", 
                  "End_Date" = "Transaction_Date"),
                list(`==`, `<=`,`>=`)) %>% 
  group_by(Country.x, Start_Date, End_Date) %>% 
  summarise(Cost = sum(Cost),
            Product = sum(Product))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   Country.x, Start_Date [?]
  Country.x Start_Date End_Date    Cost Product
  <chr>     <date>     <date>     <int>   <int>
1 id        2017-01-04 2017-01-06   311      55
2 ng        2017-02-13 2017-02-15   527      77
```

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table(df2)

dt2[dt1, on=.(Country = Country, 
              Transaction_Date >= Start_Date, 
              Transaction_Date <= End_Date), 
    .(Cost = sum(Cost), Product = sum(Product)), 
    by=.EACHI]
```

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Start_Date = structure(c(17170, 17210), class = "Date"), 
    End_Date = structure(c(17172, 17212), class = "Date"), Country = c("id", 
    "ng")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Transaction_Date = structure(c(17170, 17171, 17211, 
17212, 17215), class = "Date"), Country = c("id", "id", "ng", 
"ng", "ng"), Cost = c(111L, 200L, 213L, 314L, 515L), Product = c(21L, 
34L, 45L, 32L, 26L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```